# Query doesn't work when adding another condition with PARTITION BY

Tags: sql

Originally I had the following query:

```
SELECT T.* FROM
  (SELECT *, row_number() OVER
    (PARTITION BY manager_id ORDER BY id) AS sn FROM my_table) T
       WHERE (sn = 1)
       AND ((checkbox IS NULL OR (checkbox = 0)
  )
```

but then I added another boolean column to the db called "not_relevant" and I want to show results where its value is not 1, so I added the following:

```
SELECT T.* FROM
  (SELECT *, row_number() OVER
    (PARTITION BY manager_id ORDER BY id) AS sn FROM my_table) T
       WHERE (sn = 1)
       AND ((checkbox IS NULL) OR (checkbox = 0) 
       AND (not_relevant != 1)
  )
```

But I get the same results even if `not_relevant` is 1

Why?

Comment: Seems to me that your syntax (usage of parantheses) is incorrect and therefore so your logic, too. I advice to remove all unncessary parantheses and try again. To be more specific: I guess "AND ((checkbox IS NULL) OR (checkbox = 0)"  must be "AND (checkbox IS NULL OR checkbox = 0)" instead.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms